# Could not find main class file. Program will exit. Export runnable jar

Tags: java, program-entry-point, executable-jar

I have a game clone that I want to export as a jar runnable file. It says it cannot find the main class file, so I checked with cmd
entered "java -jar TetrisClone.jar" and this came up which also brings me to my second problem.
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8qX5.png) -

I have resources such as images and colors that are being imported outside the src/com/sambalana. But nside the jar I created the folders have not been imported into the jar runnable.

Here is a download link to my project: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jts12hxuq6ybdnl/TetrisProject.zip?dl=0

Extract zip, import folder to Eclipse Project Workspace.

Comment: Your Jar manifest doesn't indicate a valid main class.

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: My manifest file says "com.Sambalana.MAIN"

Comment: Class Path: . (just a dot notation)

Comment: I have a class called Main where the main() is.

Comment: Resources I import are folders, that are outside src folder (src/com/sambalana/classes...)

Answer (score 0):

Your project seems fine. You gotta do following steps in eclipse ide:-
1. Right click on your project then click on export.
2. Under Java section choose "Runnable jar file" and click next.
3. In configuration window choose main file of your project(in launch configuration) and click finish.
Now copy all your folders(colors, fonts, images, pieces, sound) and paste where you created jar file.
That's it whoooo!!! Run your jar file by double clicking on it.